# Is there no Google Player API for Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides-api

We have a ruby on rails learning app. We have imported various Google Slides presentations using embed code. We are aware an API exists with a Ruby Gem to create/import slides within our APP (https://developers.google.com/slides/)

But we need greater control over the slides. Is there no Google Player API ? We need to detect start and stop points essentially. This will help us set a completion flag and also show and hide our player buttons. Otherwise the user will see our player buttons and the google player buttons... It seems other people have similar issues and need more control over the player aspects as I've seen similar posts. Please help!!!

Comment: AFAIK, [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/overview) is used to create beautiful slide decks automatically from user- and system-provided data. There is no available function for it to detect the start and endpoint of a slide. The closest would be [Presentation Operations](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/presentation) and [Slide Operations](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/slides) this allows you to manage existing presentation files and create new ones and to create, move, and delete slides (respectively).

Comment: You can also report a feature request with details of this feature. Hope this helps.